# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') discord v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, SelectMenuBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const client = require("../../index");
const config = require("../../botconfig");
const create_menu = require("../../models/helpMenu.js");
const prefixSchema = require("../../models/prefix");

module.exports = {
  name: "help",
  description: "Displays all available command categories!",
  aliases: [],
  usage: "<command> or <category>",
  run: async (client, interaction, message, args, db) => {
    //try {
    const data = await prefixSchema.findOne({ Guild: message.guildId });

    if (data) {
      let categories = [];
      let cots = [];

      if (!args[0]) {
        let ignored = ["Giveaway", "Owner"];

        const emoji = {
          Action: "",
          Admin: "",
          Birthday: "",
          Fun: "",
          Giveaway: "",
          Image: "️",
          Minigame: "",
          Miscellaneous: "⚙️",
          Moderation: "️",
          Owner: "",
          Ticket: "",
        };

        let cmdCategory = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;

          const name = `${emoji[dir]} - ${dir}`;

          let categoryName = dir;

          let categoryDir = new Object();

          categoryDir = {
            name: name,
            value: "​",
            inline: true,
          };

          categories.push(categoryDir);
          cmdCategory.push(categoryName);
        });

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle("__Crimson's Help Menu__")
          .setDescription(`>>> Default Prefix: \`${config.defaultPrefix}\`\nServer Prefix: \`${data.Prefix}\``)
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addFields(categories)
          .setColor("#EE1C25")
          .setFooter({ text: "Navigate through the embeds using the provided menu below.", iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() })
          .setTimestamp();

        let menus = create_menu(cmdCategory);
        return message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } }).then((msg) => {
            const menuID = menus.sid;

            const select = async (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.customId != menuID) return;

              let { values } = interaction;

              let value = values[0];

              let commands2 = [];

              readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
                if (dir.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()) return;
                const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

                const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                  let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

                  if (!file.name) return "No command name.";

                  let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

                  if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

                  let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
                  let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "• ";

                  let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

                  return obj;
                });

                let dota = new Object();

                cmds.map((co) => {
                  if (co == undefined) return;

                  dota = {
                    name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "Processing..." : co.cname}`,
                    value: "​",
                    inline: false,
                  };
                  commands2.push(dota);
                });

                cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
              });

              if (cots.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                const cmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .setTitle(`__${value.charAt(0) + value.slice(1)} Commands__`)
                  .addFields(commands2)
                  .setColor("#EE1C25");

                await interaction.deferUpdate();

                return interaction.message.edit({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
              }
            };

            const filter = (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) return true;
              return interaction.reply({ content: "<:CL_VoteCross:781265541804720148> You cannot use this menu.", ephemeral: true });
            };

            const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: "SelectMenu" });
            collector.on("collect", select);
            collector.on("end", () => null);
          });
      } else {
        let commands2 = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (dir.toLowerCase() !== args[0].toLowerCase()) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
            let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

            if (!file.name) return "I was unable to fetch the requested command.";

            let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

            if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

            let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
            let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "";

            let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

            return obj;
          });

          let dota = new Object();

          cmds.map((co) => {
            if (co == undefined) return;

            dota = {
              name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress..." : "• " + co.cname}`,
              value: "​",
              inline: true,
            };
            commands2.push(dota);
          });

          cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
        });

        const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || client.commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase()));

        if (cots.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
          const cmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`__${args[0].charAt(0) + args[0].slice(1)} commands__`)
            .addFields(commands2)
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return message.reply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        if (!command) {
          const noCmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Unknown Command/Category")
            .setDescription(`The command or category you are trying to find is not in our database, if you think this is a mistake.. please let us know!\n\n\n**Options**\n\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <category name>\`\`\` \`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <command name>\`\`\``)
            .setFooter({ text: `Command Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return await message.reply({ embeds: [noCmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        const cmdDetailsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(`**Command:** \`${command.name}\``)
          .addFields(
            {
              name: "Usage",
              value: command.usage
                ? `\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`\`\``
                : "`No usage for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Description",
              value: command.description
                ? `\`\`\`${command.description}\`\`\``
                : "`No description for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Aliases",
              value: command.aliases
                ? `\`\`\`${command.aliases.join(", ")}\`\`\``
                : "`No aliases for this command`",
            }
          )
          .setFooter({ text: `Command Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor("#EE1C25");
        return await message.reply({ embeds: [cmdDetailsEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
      }
    } else if (!data) {
      let categories = [];
      let cots = [];

      if (!args[0]) {
        let ignored = ["Giveaway", "Owner"];

        const emoji = {
          Action: "",
          Admin: "",
          Birthday: "",
          Fun: "",
          Giveaway: "",
          Image: "️",
          Minigame: "",
          Miscellaneous: "⚙️",
          Moderation: "️",
          Owner: "",
          Ticket: "",
        };

        let cmdCategory = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;

          const name = `${emoji[dir]} - ${dir}`;

          let categoryName = dir;

          let categoryDir = new Object();

          categoryDir = {
            name: name,
            value: "​",
            inline: true, //true
          };

          categories.push(categoryDir);
          cmdCategory.push(categoryName);
        });

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle("__Crimson's Help Menu__")
          .setDescription(`>>> Default Prefix: \`${config.defaultPrefix}\`\nServer Prefix: \`none\``)
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addFields(categories)
          .setColor("#EE1C25")
          .setFooter({ text: "Navigate through the embeds using the provided menu below.", iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() })
          .setTimestamp();

        let menus = create_menu(cmdCategory);
        return message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } }).then((msg) => {
            const menuID = menus.sid;

            const select = async (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.customId != menuID) return;

              let { values } = interaction;

              let value = values[0];

              let commands2 = [];

              readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
                if (dir.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()) return;
                const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

                const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                  let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

                  if (!file.name) return "No command name.";

                  let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

                  if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

                  let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
                  let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "• ";

                  let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

                  return obj;
                });

                let dota = new Object();

                cmds.map((co) => {
                  if (co == undefined) return;

                  dota = {
                    name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "Processing..." : co.cname}`,
                    value: "​",
                    inline: false, //true
                  };
                  commands2.push(dota);
                });

                cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
              });

              if (cots.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                const cmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .setTitle(`__${value.charAt(0) + value.slice(1)} Commands__`)
                  .addFields(commands2)
                  .setColor("#EE1C25");

                await interaction.deferUpdate();

                return interaction.message.edit({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
              }
            };

            const filter = (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) return true;
              return interaction.reply({ content: "<:CL_VoteCross:781265541804720148> This menu is not for you.", ephemeral: true });
            };

            const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: "SelectMenu" });
            collector.on("collect", select);
            collector.on("end", () => null);
          });
      } else {
        let commands2 = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (dir.toLowerCase() !== args[0].toLowerCase()) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
            let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

            if (!file.name) return "I was unable to fetch the requested command.";

            let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

            if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

            let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
            let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "";

            let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

            return obj;
          });

          let dota = new Object();

          cmds.map((co) => {
            if (co == undefined) return;

            dota = {
              name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress..." : "• " + co.cname}`,
              value: "​",
              inline: false, //true
            };
            commands2.push(dota);
          });

          cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
        });

        const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || client.commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase()));

        if (cots.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
          const cmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`__${args[0].charAt(0) + args[0].slice(1)} commands__`)
            .addFields(commands2)
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return message.reply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        if (!command) {
          const noCmdEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Unknown Command/Category")
            .setDescription(`The command or category you are trying to find is not in our database, if you think this is a mistake.. please let us know!\n\n\n**Options**\n\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <category name>\`\`\` \`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <command name>\`\`\``)
            .setFooter({ text: `Command Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return await message.reply({ embeds: [noCmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        const cmdDetailsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(`**Command:** \`${command.name}\``)
          .addFields(
            {
              name: "Usage",
              value: command.usage
                ? `\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`\`\``
                : "`No usage for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Description",
              value: command.description
                ? `\`\`\`${command.description}\`\`\``
                : "`No description for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Aliases",
              value: command.aliases
                ? `\`\`\`${command.aliases.join(", ")}\`\`\``
                : "`No aliases for this command`",
            })
          .setFooter({ text: `Command Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor("#EE1C25");
        return await message.reply({ embeds: [cmdDetailsEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
      }
    }
  //} catch (err) {
    //console.log(err)
    //return await message.reply(`\`${err}\``);
  //}
 },
};
```

Error:

```
/app/commands/Miscellaneous/help.js:234
if (!args[0]) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I’m still changing stuff over to v14 of discord, and I appear to keep breaking/not understanding half the errors that I keep getting and some past one such as the one below about `message.guild.id`.

Other Error:

```
const data = await prefixSchema.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id });

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

index.js

```
/*Discord V14 Setup*/
const { Client, Routes, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, Collection, EmbedBuilder, MessageAttachment, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder } = require('discord.js'),
    botconfig = require('./botconfig.js'),
    ownerID = botconfig.ownerID,
    client = new Client({ allowedMentions: { parse: ['roles', 'everyone', 'users'], repliedUser: false }, partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction], intents: [GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans, GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations, GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks, GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping] });
/*End of Discord V14 Setup*/

/*Slash Commands*/
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const fs = require('fs');
/*End of Slash Commands*/

/*Packages*/
const { DiscordTogether } = require('discord-together');
const { Captcha } = require('captcha-canvas');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
const Canvacord = require('canvacord');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const quick = require('quick.db');
/*End of Packages*/

/*Models for Client*/
const { events } = require('./handlers/events');
//const { slashCommands } = require('./handlers/slash');
const leaveSchema = require('./models/leaveLogs');
const loggerHandler = require('./handlers/logger.js');
const modlogsSchema = require('./models/modLogs');
const prefixSchema = require('./models/prefix');
const welcomeSchema = require('./models/joinLogs');
/*End of Models for Client*/

/*Configurations*/
module.exports = client;
client.aliases = new Collection();
client.botconfig = botconfig;
client.commands = new Collection();
client.db = quick.db;
client.discordTogether = new DiscordTogether(client);
client.embed = new EmbedBuilder();
client.logger = new loggerHandler();
client.slash = new Collection();
client.snipes = new Collection();

/*End of Configurations*/

/*Client categories*/
client.categories = fs.readdirSync('./commands/');

['command'].forEach(handler => { 
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});
/*End of Client categories*/

/*MongoDB Setup*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(botconfig.db_uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }).then(client.logger.log('READY', 'Crimson has successfully connected to MongoDB!'));
/*End of MongoDB Setup*/

/*reaction-roles*/
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, member, guild, message) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (member.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('746023960201920523');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('857984203346018305');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '❗') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('858546783823462430');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('889927145206468669');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('746024349135405199');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('746024204989759632');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('889927622774124574');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '924001444980478012') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '<a:CL_CheckMark:858853559940808724>');
        await reaction.users.remove(member.id);
        
        const captcha = new Captcha();
        captcha.async = true;
        captcha.addDecoy();
        captcha.drawTrace();
        captcha.drawCaptcha();

        const captchaAttachment = new MessageAttachment(await captcha.png, 'CrimsonCaptcha.png');
        const captchaEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Crimson\'s Lounge - Checkpoint ')
            .setDescription('Solve the captcha code to gain access to `Crimson\'s Lounge`')
            .setImage('attachment://CrimsonCaptcha.png')
            .setColor('EE1C25')
            .setFooter('This code will expire in 5 minutes')
            .setTimestamp();
    
        const msg = await member.send({ embeds: [captchaEmbed], files: [captchaAttachment] }).catch(() => null);
        const filter = message => {
            if (message.author.id !== member.id) return;
            if (message.content === captcha.text) return true;
            else member.send('Incorrect Captcha, Please try again.');
        };
    
        try {
            const response = await msg.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ['time'] });
            if (response) {
                const completeCaptchaEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle('<:CL_VoteTick:781265299609223188> Verification Complete') //✅
                    .setDescription('You have successfully gained access to `Crimson\'s Lounge`.')
                    .setColor('GREEN')
                    .setTimestamp();
                member.send({ embeds: [completeCaptchaEmbed] });
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.add('828466951201751071');
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.remove('903403824818028555');
            }
            if (response === false) {
                const failedCaptchaEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle('<:CL_VoteCross:781265541804720148> Verification Failed') //❌
                    .setDescription('> You did not complete the captcha in the given time (5 mins)\n\n`You were kicked from `Crimson\'s Lounge`, feel free to join us again with the click of the magical button below!`')
                    .setColor('RED')
                    .setFooter('If you are having trouble verifying, let our support team know.')
                    .setTimestamp();
                member.kick();
        
                let failedBtn = new MessageButton()
                    .setStyle('LINK')
                    .setURL('https://discord.gg/DFZv2Zh')
                    .setLabel('Support');
        
                let row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents([failedBtn]);
                const targetMember = await member.send({ embeds: [failedCaptchaEmbed], components: [row] });
                const filter = button => button.clicker.user.id === member.user.id;
                const collector = targetMember.createMessageComponentCollector(filter);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('746023960201920523');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('857984203346018305');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '❗') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('858546783823462430');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('889927145206468669');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('746024349135405199');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('746024204989759632');
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.id === '931609070501265408') {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('889927622774124574');
        }
    }
});
/*End of Reaction Roles*/

/*Welcome System*/
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member, guild) => {
    welcomeSchema.findOne({ Guild: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if (!data) return;
    
        const user = member.user;
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.Channel);
    
        var welcomeMessage = [`**${user.username}** Just landed.`, `Yay you made it, **${user.username}**!`, `Good to see you, **${user.username}**.`, `**${user.username}** just slid into the server.`, `**${user.username}** joined the party.`, `Welcome, **${user.username}**. We hope you brought pizza.`, `**${user.username}** hopped into the server.`, `**${user.username}** just showed up!`, `Glad you're here, **${user.username}**.`, `Everyone welcome **${user.username}**!`, `**${user.username}** is here.`, `A wild **${user.username}** appeared.`];
    
        const welcomeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<:CL_JoinArrow:781262371514875904>  ${welcomeMessage[Math.floor(Math.random() * welcomeMessage.length)]}`)
            .setFooter(`Member #${member.guild.memberCount}`, member.guild.iconURL())
            .setColor('GREEN');
        channel.send({ embeds: [welcomeEmbed] });
    
        if (member.guild.id == '705344500507345017') {
            const role = member.guild.roles.cache.get('903403824818028555');
            await member.roles.add(role.id);
        }
    });
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member, guild) => {
    leaveSchema.findOne({ Guild: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if (!data) return;
    
        const user = member.user;
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.Channel);
    
        var leaveMessage = [`**${user.username}**, It's sad to see you go.`, `Come back soon, **${user.username}**.`, `It appears that **${user.username}** has parted ways.`, `**${user.username}** just took the leap of faith.`, `**${user.username}** left the party.`, `Goodbye, **${user.username}**.`, `**${user.username}** took the easy way out.`, `**${user.username}** has left us.`, `Glad you're here, **${user.username}**.`, `**${user.username}**, come back.. we already miss you :(`, `**${user.username}** has disappeared into the dark.`, `A wild **${user.username}** has disappeared.`];
    
        const leaveEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<:CL_LeaveArrow:781262397662167090>  ${leaveMessage[Math.floor(Math.random() * leaveMessage.length)]}`)
            .setFooter(`That leaves us with #${member.guild.memberCount} members`, member.guild.iconURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor('RED');
        channel.send({ embeds: [leaveEmbed] });
    });
});
/*End of welcome System*/

client.login(botconfig.token);
```

Comment: Can you provide your main file where you handle the commands? Sometimes these errors are caused due to the incorrect order of the provided arguments

Comment: So you want my index.js file?

Comment: Yes, your `index.js` file

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the message

Comment: I'm not that familiar with discord, however, from a pure javascript perspective the errors are telling you the properties you are trying to access are undefined. Which I know you know. Just trying to step through my thought process to troubleshoot. If those properties are undefined then there seems to be a timing issue on when your code is trying to access them. What other required files need to load before those objects are defined?

Comment: The event folders

Comment: The event *files

Comment: Can you also show your command handler file? Sorry for the late response